# How to insert JavaScript code in a Handlebars template?

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

Quoting [Handlebars FAQ:](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/FAQ.md)

> How can I include script tags in my template?
>
> If loading the template via an inlined  tag then you may need to break up the script tag with an empty comment to avoid browser parser errors:
>
> ```
> <script type="text/x-handlebars">
>   foo
>   <scr{{!}}ipt src="bar"></scr{{!}}ipt>
> </script>
> ```

Nevertheless, I can't seem to be able to implement this:

```js
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 
  Handlebars.compile(
    document.getElementById("template").innerHTML
  )({});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.10/handlebars.js"></script>

<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars">
  foo
  <scr{{!}}ipt>
    alert("Yay!");
  </scr{{!}}ipt>
</script>

<div id="output"></div>
```

As you can see no `Yay!` is alerted.

How to make this work?

Comment: It works if I use jQuery `.html()` though instead of `innerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same with jQuery's `.html()` and it worked fine. I could narrow down on `.innerHTML` being the culprit when I looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml) answer.

In short, `script` tags inserted with `.innerHTML` needs to be explicitly evaluated using `eval()`.

So below code works, if you eval the script:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = (Handlebars.compile(
    document.getElementById("template").innerHTML
  ))({});

  eval(document.getElementById("myscript").innerHTML); // explicitly eval the script


}, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.10/handlebars.js"></script>

<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars">
  foo
  <scr{{!}}ipt id="myscript" src="bar">console.log("Hello")</scr{{!}}ipt>
</script>

<div id="output"></div>
```